# Has the majority of Jews followed the decrees of the sages by the 7th century?

Tags: minhag, history, orthodox, conservative-judaism

Can we say that the majority of Jews followed the decrees of the sages by the 7th century? Maybe earlier? Any proofs?

Comment: Why the seventh specifically?

Comment: because I try to guess, to what form of Judaism, belonged the persecuted Jews of Arabia  by the 7th century?  what I'm sure of, is that the Talmud and midrash (whom Muhammad borrowed from) were available to Muhammad in his environment? may be that is a clue to know that they followed the decrees of the sages ( called rabbinic Judaism)? Are there any other ways to know what form of Judaism, belonged the persecuted Jews of Arabia by the 7th century? could any Jews outside those who followed the decrees of the sages ,have followed the teaching of the Talmud and the midrash ?? thank you for answer

Comment: See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118699/20472) for some info on the observance levels of the Jews in the Arab countries of Khadayev and Meishan in the 1st-2nd centuries and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118774/20472) for a little info on the Jewish community in Arabia. Note that there are disagreements about the observance levels of the Jews that Muhammad knew.