# Do non-Israelite soldiers in the army of an Israelite king observe Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, malchut-royalty, army-military-war

Does וְגֵרְךָ, אֲשֶׁר בִּשְׁעָרֶיךָ apply to non-Israelite soldiers serving in the army of an Israelite king?

Comment: What makes you think non-Israelite soldiers serving in the army of an Israelite king might be different from other non-Israelite civilians who live under an Israelite king's rule?

Comment: Also, why do you use the terms Israelite/non-Israelite?

Comment: "why do you use the terms Israelite/non-Israelite?" because they have not naturalized.

I'm wondering about the case if they are risking their lives and specifically injured in a מלחמת מצווה milchemet mitzvah ... a soldier is like an eved actually isn't an even more pointed form of avodah?

Comment: (1) "_because they have not naturalized._" What I meant to ask was: Why do you use the term 'Israelite', and not 'Jewish' (or 'non-Israelite', and not 'non-Jewish')? (2) "_I'm wondering about the case if they are risking their lives and specifically injured in a מלחמת מצווה milchemet mitzvah_". What does that have to do with their [non-]obligation to observe Shabbat? (3) "_a soldier is like an eved actually isn't an even more pointed form of avodah?_" Any more so than an employee at a company, or a nurse at a hospital? What make you think that?

Comment: "Why do you use the term 'Israelite', and not 'Jewish' (or 'non-Israelite', and not 'non-Jewish')?" 

To exclude the case of a Jewish king of proselyte ancestry specifically for this question. Different legal situations.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136917/royal-convert-still-royal/136940#comment456299_136940
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40429/what-is-known-about-the-sage-מונבז/119053#119053


"What make you think that?"

They serve on command and are risking their lives as a regular part of work.

Comment: "_To exclude the case of a Jewish king of proselyte ancestry specifically for this question._" (1) Then, you should state that in the question, as I don't think many people define 'Israelite' that way. See "[What's the difference between 'Jew', 'Israelite' and 'Judaizer'](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15779/1368)", where other definitions of 'Israelite' are given. (2) Do you use 'non-Israelite' (as in "non-Israelite soldiers") to include Jews of proselyte ancestry?

Comment: "_They serve on command and are risking their lives as a regular part of work._" (1) So do fire-fighters in peace time. (2) What about an Israelite soldier? Wouldn't that mean he is also an _eved_? Do you believe he should be released after 6 years (in line with וּבַשָּׁנָה, הַשְּׁבִיעִת, תְּשַׁלְּחֶנּוּ חָפְשִׁי, מֵעִמָּךְ)? (3) (More generally:) From where do you get this definition of '_eved_'?

Comment: Firefighters are workers who can quit at-will. If a firefighter decides to quit the moment the firehouse alarm goes off he can, he might be looked down upon but a soldier on the other hand might be shot or imprisoned for deserting depending on the army ...

It seems the character of 'conscription' is what bears.

It would seem odd to me if an Israelite king conscripted soldiers for a term longer than 6 yrs ... it would not seem odd if the soldiers of a righteous king chose to serve indefinitely with ahavah and zeal ⚡.